# Is it possible to populate a listbox with a sortedlist? C#/WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently making a scoreboard for a hangman based game for a university project.

I have been told to create a scoreboard showing the lowest amount of guesses for each word, using a listbox to display the word+lowest guesses and a sortedlist for storing these values.

I am able to get my lowest guesses score into a sortedlist, however I am now struggling to find a way in order to display it in the listbox.

I have tried using the `listbox.DataSource` property in order to populate it, however I get the following error as well as the line of code:

```
lsbScores.DataSource = scores;
```

> System.ArgumentException: 'Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.'

I have also thought to possibly make a loop and go through the values in my sortedlist, however that feels like the wrong approach, if this is the right approach, how would I go about doing this?

It feels to me using a sortedlist is the wrong approach in general, however it is how I have been told to do it, so I will need to.

Comment: `lsbScores.DataSource = scores.Values.ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined a form level variable something like this

```cs
private SortedList<int, string> scores = new();
```

In the form designer, select the ListBox, select properties then select DisplayMember to Value.

In code, use .ToList on scores.

```cs
lsbScores.DataSource = scores.ToList();
```

To Show both `word+lowest guesses`

Create a class, for example, the following where .ToString will be used as DisplayMember for the ListBox.

```cs
public class Guess
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Key} - {Value}";
}
```

Mock-up for assigning data to the ListBox

```cs
lsbScores.DataSource = scores
    .Select(x => new Guess()
    {
        Key = x.Key,
        Value = x.Value
    }).ToList(); ;
```

To get at say the current item in the ListBox.

```cs
if (lsbScores.SelectedItem is not null)
{
    Guess current = (Guess)lsbScores.SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception says what you can try doing:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an **IList** or an IListSource.'

(**bold** is mine, Dmitrii)

you can provide collection of required type with a help of Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// You may want to use scores.Keys instead of scores.Values
lsbScores.DataSource = scores.Values.ToList();
```